How to add months to a column and create multiple columns based on frequency in pandas
I have a DF below
DF
ID  name    qty price   date      Freq
1   abc     20   3   17/01/2022    4
1   abc     10   5   18/03/2022    3
2   def     10   7   24/01/2022    1
2   def     40   2   25/05/2022    6
3   ghi    322   7   4/5/2022      12

My expectation is to add freq to date column by months and project for 12 months.
and multiple qty with price as Amt columns and display the same value for the proj months.
Expected Output

Solution I tried
DF['col1'] = DF.apply(lambda x:x['date'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=x['Freq']),1).
I know the above query just add months but I need to project this for 12 months as mentioned in expected output.
Note1 - Col5 goes till col12 since I projecting it for 12 months.

Your "project for 12 months" logic is unclear, please break down your example. Why do you have empty cells?

reason why I have empty cells is because from col1 you add freq and next date should be on the freq added month. Eg: if the freq is 4 and its month is Feb, you add 4 month and then next month would be on Jun.. Hence there are empty cells

Sorry, but it's unclear, please provide an explicit description for each cell (as [edit])

OK, got it, but what is val? sometimes you take Freq, sometimes Amount

my intention to add 12 months from date column and only for the expected month you will find value and rest would empty cells.

val is just the amt col getting repeated to the freq month.

You can convert to_datetime, then add a multiple of months with DateOffset, the pivot:
df['Amt'] = df['qty']*df['price']
n = df['Freq'].rfloordiv(12)
tmp = df.loc[df.index.repeat(n)]
idx = tmp.groupby(level=0).cumcount()*tmp['Freq']

out = (tmp.assign(idx=idx,
                  Col=pd.to_datetime(tmp['date'].add(pd.DateOffset(months=1)*(idx+tmp['Freq']))),
                  Val=tmp['Amt'])
          .pivot(columns='idx', values=['Col', 'Val'])
          .sort_index(level=1, axis=1, sort_remaining=False)
      )

out.columns = out.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]} {x[1]+1}')

out = df.join(out)

Output:
   ID name  qty  price       date  Freq   Amt      Col 1 Val 1      Col 2 Val 2      Col 3 Val 3      Col 4 Val 4      Col 5 Val 5      Col 6 Val 6      Col 7 Val 7      Col 8 Val 8      Col 9 Val 9     Col 10 Val 10     Col 11 Val 11     Col 12 Val 12
0   1  abc   20      3 2022-01-17     4    60 2022-05-17    60        NaT   NaN        NaT   NaN        NaT   NaN 2022-09-17    60        NaT   NaN        NaT   NaN        NaT   NaN 2023-01-17    60        NaT    NaN        NaT    NaN        NaT    NaN
1   1  abc   10      5 2022-03-18     3    50 2022-06-18    50        NaT   NaN        NaT   NaN 2022-09-18    50        NaT   NaN        NaT   NaN 2022-12-18    50        NaT   NaN        NaT   NaN 2023-03-18     50        NaT    NaN        NaT    NaN
2   2  def   10      7 2022-01-24     1    70 2022-02-24    70 2022-03-24    70 2022-04-24    70 2022-05-24    70 2022-06-24    70 2022-07-24    70 2022-08-24    70 2022-09-24    70 2022-10-24    70 2022-11-24     70 2022-12-24     70 2023-01-24     70
3   2  def   40      2 2022-05-25     6    80 2022-11-25    80        NaT   NaN        NaT   NaN        NaT   NaN        NaT   NaN        NaT   NaN 2023-05-25    80        NaT   NaN        NaT   NaN        NaT    NaN        NaT    NaN        NaT    NaN
4   3  ghi  322      7 2022-05-04    12  2254 2023-05-04  2254        NaT   NaN        NaT   NaN        NaT   NaN        NaT   NaN        NaT   NaN        NaT   NaN        NaT   NaN        NaT   NaN        NaT    NaN        NaT    NaN        NaT    NaN


Thanks for you inputs. But im looking to project for 12 months. not just stop with col1.

@arawind73 can you double check your provided output? IS it complete?

Ive given the complete expected output.

I get ValueError: repeats may not contain negative values. when i run this code "tmp = df.loc[df.index.repeat(n)] "

@arawind73 do you have negative values in Freq? your example doesn't demonstrate that. You can ensure all values are positive with df['Freq']= df['Freq'].abs()
